# I take it so long everytime I learn mathematics myself. What should I do?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning

Stack-Exchange,
I am a freshman in Mathematics Department.

I always learn mathematics the hard way. Everytime I learn mathematics on my own by reading from Mathematics textbooks, I would read the definition, try to figure out what it really means, stick new definitions which concepts that I already know, prove theorem without ever reading given proof.

But recently, I find this method cumbersome. In order to get a deep level of understanding those concept and solve a good amount of problems, I trade it off with a lot of my time, and my energy.

My seniors tell me that I should learn from different source of material to get more insight view, and separate the processes of learning theory and problem solving. I should read all the theory before trying to apply them to save times. But I'm used to the way of Pólya's mouse, so I am worried that I won't be able to catch up with all my classes like this. I want to try the way my seniors told me; that might be faster. But I want to know if the method would come with a loss of depth in understanding.

So I am asking for help. Also, please give me some tips to boost up the performance and the quality of learning mathematics all by myself. Thank you all very much.

Comment: Nice question, however, not typical in this community.

Comment: Thank you, and I am so sorry that I might have asked in a wrong place.

Comment: What is your maths level ?

Comment: @user1952009 What do you mean by level?

Comment: @MichaelDNguyen It is obvious : what is your level ? What are you studying those days ?

Comment: @user1952009 I am a freshman at college. I'm currently studying Linear Algebra and Calculus 1A.

Comment: I'd try asking this type of question in [Academia@CS](http://academia.stackexchange.com). There are many mathematicians who hang out there, and, honestly, you are getting pretty useless answers here.

Comment: It takes all of us a very long time. You will be okay. I promise.

Comment: There is a Mathematical Education exchange site on this network. You should ask there.

Comment: Unfortunately, no one can be told what the Matrix is. You have to see it for yourself.

Answer (score 20):

I will try to give an idea of what I did when I was in your situation (It worked for me, and I hope it will work for you too).

I had a teacher who used to say self learning is best learning. I was one of the strong believer of his philosophy. He once said, being a teacher I can only do one things for you which is Introducing the beauty of subject to you. The main thing in learning is the efforts you give.

Now since you are studying such a great subject on your own, You should have two things.

$1$. **Interest in the subject**

$2$.**Patience**.

Mathematics is a language that attract at first, then repel and then stick to you forever. You just have to bear the period of repulsion.

The period of repulsion comes when you can't solve problems, the formulas go over your head and at that time you just start reading the solutions of problems and start convincing yourself that "Yes I am learning (Though you are not)".

The basic idea is to stick to a topic until you have a complete belief that you can do any question of that particular topic. The mathematics means solving Problems and if you can't solve problems then you can't do mathematics.

I agree with your seniors but to a small extent. You should do problems from different books but avoid use of too many books as that leads to confusion.

> So, I will sum up all the discussion regarding self learning in  points as:
>
> $1$. Bring your interest in mathematics.
>
> $2$. Be patient and don't lose confidence.
>
> $3$. Do  problems as much as possible.
>
> $4$. Avoid use of so many books until you have completed one.

Many other people can disagree with my opinions but that doesn't matter. I respect opinion of everyone that is why if you think I m wrong somewhere leave comment.Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I tend to pay too much time with the reading. Should I focus on doing problems instead? I can pay almost a whole day until I have completely understood the subject I am learning. So I want to find a way to do more works in the same amount of time. I'm currently learning Linear Algebra and Calculus A1. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Michael D Nguyen. As I mentioned in the answer, there is no need to read the theory much in mathematics, just read the theory once and start doing problems. The only thing which you should keep in mind is how to approac a perticular kind of problem.

Comment: @@THE LONE WOLF: I want follow the career of doing research in Mathematics, is it really okay If I don't dwell too much in the theory?
Can I still work it out?

Comment: @MichaelDNguyen. In my opinion you should divide your time to theory and problems such that nothing remains behind. I also want to pursue as a mathematical researcher. You read about everything in depth and the depth is attained when you find its applications and applications are simply problems. So, read theory and do application

Comment: LONE WOLF Thank you so much, I will try to do that :)

Comment: @MichaelDNguyen Always welcome.

Comment: Tips for solving all Ex given in Ch 4 of Rudin's PMA. First go through Ch 4 and mark with pencil the theorems needed to follow this Chap. Make a tree-diagram for Ch 4. Then study the proofs of all Th. You will be able to master the proofs of all theorems in Ch 4 without much hurdle and with minimum prerequisites. Repeat the same procedure to master Ch 5 and Ch 6 . Now solve the Ex given in Ch 4 disregarding the order of problems in the text.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF, on the contrary, I only spend time on the theory. Yes, problem solving is necessary, but often the degree of originality in mathematics itself can not be substituted for exercise problems. Frequently I have encountered exercise problems which don't have any importance outside of the problem itself, and required a clever 'trick' to solve. I like your advice for patience and interest, but I don't quite get this one.

Comment: Hey @Siddhant, and thanks or bringing this post in my notice as I forgot about that since December 7. Let's come to your problem now. There is no problem in doing theory part, but excess o  anything causes distraction from other things. You are challenging the importance of exercises but only a little. My teacher called the "reading theory" as eating and "Doing exercises " as digestion. I know you have problem with doing such questions which are not of much importance, then there is no problem in it. I referred to those things which are essential,  do the first which is essential.

Comment: And then those things which have a little importance only

Comment: @codetalker I agree with this (at least to some extent). There are many problems in textbooks which don't have any importance outside of the problem itself and require a 'trick' to solve. They don't give any insight or intuition to the subject, and just wear down at your confidence, because you spend so much time trying to think up of the trick yourself. Also, it's kind of stupid to expect people to be able to invent the trick itself -reinventing the trick for a problem may be as much a matter of chance as anything -sure, more intelligent people have better odds, but it's still not guaranteed.

Comment: I have to add the caveat that thinking up tricks seems to be basically what most mathematical research is about -- a theorem remains unproved until a person devises the trick to solve that theorem for the first time -- so some argue that devising tricks for problems is worthwhile for preparing for mathematical research. But devising tricks for problems with known solutions is pointless, since the solutions are already known -- if you want to practice devising tricks for mathematical research, spend your time on an actual mathematical research problem, not an already known result.

Comment: @Chill2Macht Your comment is confusing to me. It's likely there are alien civilizations that have solved much of the maths we're working on. So, then would it be "pointless" to get better at maths devising tricks even in research? Results undiscovered by a particular student are like mini-research problems. The upside is that the student can actually get the solution if they aren't able to devise the trick. Just because someone in history has gotten abs before doesn't mean all of humanity has washboard abs. Each student learns by their own efforts.

Comment: @JDG You are right. I get that the point of such problems is to prepare students for careers in mathematics research, but not everyone who wants to learn some math wants to become a math professor. Such problems aren't necessary to learn how to use the math, and therefore don't really suit the needs of the broader audience who wants to apply the topic, rather than research it. Also, in practice, unless the person who wrote the book beforehand created solutions for all of the problems and published them online, it's often difficult to find the solution if the student can't devise the trick.

Comment: @Chill2Macht You're right: Most students don't need the tricks. But then we should also design classes around student needs. A pre-med student doesn't need so much calculus. Rather, it might be better to issue a few one or two credit courses that highlight the cultural impact of calculus, as well as giving students a taste for simple derivatives, integrals, diff eqs: Focus on appreciation and piquing interest. Of course, that's in an ideal world.

Comment: @Chill2Macht As for solutions, imo it's a crime that textbooks don't publish full solutions online. Many strong students I know benefit tremendously from Chegg on the daily---it's almost like 24/7 tutor access. With self-restraint so a student gives themself a chance to struggle, full solutions are invaluable: compared with going into school for office hours/tutoring, it saves countless hours, countless dollars, multiplies the efficacy of a textbook (fully worked solutions >>> answer summaries for odds), and so on.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why, but after reading the question, remembered this saying:

> Theory is when you know everything and nothing works. Practice is when everything works and nobody knows why. In this office we combine theory and practice: nothing works and nobody knows why.

Summing up. I agree with THE LONE WOLF. And do problems as much as possible.

I would add: if you have doubts, ASK.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much :)

Comment: You are reminding me of Fraunhofer diffraction, which is mathematically wrong but works anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I had you for a teacher or a student.   I am long past the age when I can take classes in school, and everything I do is driven by curiosity.   Recently, I became interested in retro-tech and began with the table of four-place logarithms we were given in high school. (Before computers or calculators log tables were the one of the instruments by which human computing power could be amplified.)  Wow!   What a bunch of errors in that thing, but I am finding ways to weed out the worst mistakes and improve the accuracy.

I think I have discovered things about log tables that nobody else knows.   It is an empowering feeling.   And some day, when some conference needs some kind of paper, I will have one pre-generated.  Most likely this would be the HHC 2017 conference dealing with HP calculators.

It is a good way to learn.  Never quit!

Comment: Thank you so much, that is so nice of you :)

Comment: But if you continue this way, you need to keep it OUT of your resume.  Human Resource resume screeners are very intolerant of learning outside a prescribed college course.